# Solr Spellcheck index is not replicated to the slave

Tags: solr, replication, spell-checking

I am using apache-solr-1.4.1. I have a master and a slave. When I am doing “Full import” on master, the index is replicated to the slave however the spellcheck index is not.
In the master I have:

```
<str name="confFiles">solrconfig_slave.xml:solrconfig.xml,schema.xml,stopwords.txt,elevate.xml,protwords.txt,synonyms.txt</str>`
```

And in the solrconfig.xml and solrconfig_slave.xml files I have the following settings:

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>

<lst name="spellchecker">

  <str name="name">default</str>

  <str name="field">didYouMean</str>

  <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>

  <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>

 </lst>

</searchComponent>
```

If I query the slave with “&spellcheck.build=true” the index is build.
Please help

Answer (score 2):

Replication of spellcheck data is not currently supported in Solr. According to the JIRA issue: [SOLR-866 - Support replicating arbitary indices and files with java replication](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-866) this is currently an unresolved issue and has been pushed to Solr version 4.0, but still may not be resolved in that version either as I do not see any activity on the issue.

I would suggest that you ask about the status of this issue on one of the [Solr Discussion Lists](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/discussion.html) to find out more about when it might be resolved.